# Transforming to or into something else

Tags: word-usage

My doubt relies on whereas to use **to** or **into** in this specific sentence/sense: Transforming a pair of old shoes into the most awesome ones.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transform has several examples

Comment: Alchemists unsuccessfully tried to [*transform lead **in/into** gold*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transform+lead+into+gold%2Ctransform+lead+to+gold&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) As you'll see from that chart, ***into*** is heavily favoured, but there are certainly enough instances of ***in*** to justify saying that it's at least "acceptable". And obviously there's no scope for any difference in *meaning* there.